# F# standard function that invokes its argument

Tags: f#

Probably a newbie question, but is there a standard function like

```
let apply f = f()
```

in F#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not a standard function for this.

In most cases, just calling the function is shorter and more obvious than using `apply` would be, so I'm not entirely sure how this would be useful:

```
foo ()
apply foo
```

Now, you can also write application using `|>`, but that's not very nice either:

```
() |> foo
```

I guess the only place where `apply` would be useful is:

```
functions |> List.map apply
functions |> List.map (fun f -> f ())
```

Here, the version without `apply` is shorter, but I don't think it is worth having a named function in the library just for this one use case.

You could actually use `|>` here to avoid `fun`, which makes for a lovely piece of ASCII art :-), but not for something that I would ever want to see in my codebase:

```
functions |> List.map ((|>) ())
```

Comment: My use case: I have a list of functions in `rules`, and then search for a first matching with `rules |> List.choose apply |> List.tryHead`

Comment: @Mikhail If you have a list of functions that take unit (`()`) as input, but return different results every time you invoke them, then these functions aren't [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). In functional programming, you should prefer pure functions as much as possible, so perhaps a more functional design would be possible..?

Comment: @MarkSeemann They are pure. I build the list of rules by partially applying arguments to many functions, which have `unit` as the last argument. Think of 10 different rules each of them take different parameters. I apply those parameters, put them into a list and then search for a first function which yields `Some` result. `unit` is just a way to make function call lazy.

Comment: @Mikhail If you need lazy evaluation, then F# has `lazy` expressions, which sounds like a better fit...